# Adapt apt command line layout

Tags: command-line, apt, themes, configuration, layout

Heyy everybody,

after a long time of unsuccessfull research I decided to sign up here and ask the experts:

I am using different linux distributions like debian, kubuntu and fedora, so i have experienced different package managers. What I mostly liked is dnf because of the (in my opinion) clear layout before confirming an installation. It simplifies my personal workflow enormously.

So now to my question:

Is there any possibility to enable such a layout on apt?

When installing something with apt there are no spaces and paragraphs in the overview and I really hate that...

Thank you for your answers!

Kind greetings

Fabi

**Update: My expressions might be confusing, so here are two pictures:**

This is what i would like the output to look like:

[DNF Overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPayu.png)

[And this is what the output actually looks like](https://i1.wp.com/itsfoss.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Using-apt-get-commands-linux-11.jpg?ssl=1)

I hope now it´s clear what I am meaning.

Comment: Try running some apt commands with `--dry-run` (or possibly just `-s`, for a similar effect); and see whether that output is any more use for you. http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/apt-get.8.html

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show an example of what you want to change. I suspect you are referring to some output of `apt` and not the actual command line, but your question is confusing. Then, also add what you would like the output to like like instead. It might be possible to write some sort of wrapper script to do what you want, but we will need to understand what you actually need.